# short pulse suppression

Tags: digital-logic, matlab, pulse, simulink

I'm looking to build a component (simulink) that cuts off short pulses in a digital signal (that has a varying pulse length). Does anyone have an idea?

I thought about using an integrator and comparing the output value to a calculated value that would be the integral of the shortest pulse I want to keep, but it didn't really work out so far (resetting the integral to 0 at every rising edge of the digital signal).

Comment: Short.. is that under a minute or under a nS?

Comment: @Trevor_G nanosiemens? Sounds like a good insulator.

Comment: Is this to suppress a race condition? what is dV and dt?

Comment: nah it's to suppress possible interferences (pulses shorter than say 100ns)
I'm not interested in a particular component, but rather in the underlying principle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with a digital signal I would consider using a D type flip flop that was self-clocking. The incoming "raw" data (containing pulses that need to be eradicated because they are too short) is fed into an RC low pass filter followed by a schmitt trigger. The schmitt trigger will produce a logical 1 after a pulse has been present for the required amount of time as determined by the RC low pass filter.

The schmitt trigger output can then be used to clock the data through the D type flip flop. Should subsequently the "raw" data fall to 0 it can be used to clear said D type flip-flop. It's kind-of a self clocking D type circuit.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a very basic question since I'm using simulink where you can't mix analog and digital realms so well; how do you implement a trigger schmitt if the input is a digital signal? I thought these circuits were used for analog input signals only.

Comment: Schmitt triggers are often used in digital circuits as interface circuits like above and for producing delays like above. They work with analogue or digial inputs. If you can't model it, try replacing the schmitt and RC with a delay circuit.

Answer (score 2):

### Runt pulse suppressor

**Depends on spec for min. ratio of latency/glitch time**
 . ideal=1, 1st order filter with 10% loss in noise margin is ~10:1 ratio.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fISudX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ideal method needs a self clocked register that only changes state after any edge if it is still same after x ns